# Can I submit app which contains zip package in bundle?

Tags: app-store

Can I submit app which contains zip package in bundle? Will I get rejected by AppStore for any reason?

Comment: Depends on what and how much is in the zip package, among other things.

Comment: Pictures, audios, and some texts, about 2MB totally. Could you please give me any document about it? Thanks~